# Issues with redirecting using rewrite rule .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've searched the forums, but I'm stuck.

I am switching from Miva to Opencart and going from dynamic urls to seo friendly.

I have this right now:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Screen=PROD&Store_Code=SI&Product_Code(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/catalog/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^Screen=PROD&Product_Code=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name/catalog/ [R=301,L]
```

It sends all my old google links to my catalog front page. It's a first step I guess.

The old product codes in Miva are now the Model numbers in Opencart so what the heck do I put in that last path to call out the model code? I want it to look like the search results page in Opencart:

`www.domain-name.com/catalog/786005`

Someone must be able to see what I'm missing here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is use the backreference from the query string that you used in the condition in the rewriterule using the `%1` that you captured. You were close. You can also consolidate it down to one rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} Product_Code=(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain-name.com/catalog/%1? [R=301,L]
```

Let me know how that works out for you.

Comment: I was really overthinking it, your solution was perfect.

Comment: @LJSalim ok please be sure and accept the answer if it helped you.